# Show that the ball $\{x:|x|\le 1\}$ is admissible in $\Bbb{R}^n$ without showing its boundary is measure zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Show that the ball $\{x:|x|\le 1\}$ is admissible in $\Bbb{R}^n$ without showing its boundary is measure zero.

I am taking a course in Analysis 3 again and the notations are quite new and confusing to me. **A set $E$ was defined to be Admissible if $1_E$ is integrable.** A corollary also states that:

> If $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}$ is integrable, then $E=\{(x,t):x\in \Bbb{R}^n,0<t<f(x)\}$ is admissible.

What I tried to do, using this corollary, is taking: $f(x)=1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x^2_i,f:\Bbb{R}^{n-1}\to \Bbb{R}$. If $x(\in\Bbb{R}^n)<1$ then $x^2_n<1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x^2_i$ and thus $x\in E$, and vice versa. What I am not sure about is showing that the above $f$ is actually integrable (in these dimensions integrability has a more profound meaning, and so has differentiability.)

I would really appreciate any suggestions\remarks on it.

Comment: What does "admissible" mean here?

Comment: I stressed it out.

Comment: By "integrable" do you mean Lebesgue integrable? Riemann integrable?

Comment: It wasn't mentioned so I don't want to mislead. It does have to do with lower and upper Darboux Sums equaling each other.

Comment: Take $f(x)$ as you have it for $x = (x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}) \in \mathbb R^{n-1}$ such that $x_1^2 + \cdots + x_{n-1}^2 \leq 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then $f$ is continuous [why?] and hence integrable.